# Failing to get websocket response in python

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to create a really simple websocket server with native `socket` package (this is mostly for a microcontoller but that's not relevant).
If I understand correctly, websocket is simply an extension of HTTP protocol with an upgrade request from client which then server responds back with right headers including the hashed key after proper websocket handshake. I'm oversimplifying here but that's the basic gist of what websocket is from my understanding and it should work similar to HTTP in terms of initiating connection.

So my initial pseudo code was something like this:

- Bind a socket to a port and listen
- When a client makes a websocket request, check if `connection` header has `upgrade` and `Upgrade` header has `websocket` values
- If the above is true then continue or else close the socket
- Get the value from `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header (this is for the response header `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` later)
- Generate a proper response header i.e.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: <hashed_key_from_Sec-WebSocket-Key>
```

> Note that the extra newline is intentional as per HTTP spec.

- Send it back to client

Here is my minimal python code

```py
import socket
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1

PORT = 8082

def response_key(key):
    GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" # magic string
    hash = sha1(key.encode() + GUID.encode())
    response_key = b64encode(hash.digest()).strip()
    return response_key.decode("ASCII")

def shake_hand(key):
    response = (
        "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
        f"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {response_key(key)}\r\n"
        "\r\n"
    )
    return response

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(("localhost", PORT))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        request = conn.recv(1024).strip().decode()
        data = request.split("\r\n")
        headers = {}
        for h in data:
            header = h.split(": ")
            if len(header) > 1:
                key, value = map(lambda x: x.strip().lower(), header)
                headers[key] = value

        if (headers.get("connection") == "upgrade") and (headers.get("upgrade") == "websocket"):
            handshake_response = shake_hand(
                headers["sec-websocket-key"]
            )
            conn.sendall(handshake_response.encode())
```

And the way I'm initiating websocket connection is simply from a browser console with the following code:

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8082');
ws.onopen = e => console.log("Connection open!")
ws.onerror = e => console.error(e);
ws.onmessage = e => console.log("Msg", e);
ws.onclose = e => console.log("Connection closed!")
```

However, this isn't working and it gives me an error like

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8082/' failed:
```

and there is no response header when I check the network tab.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here and I'm sort of running out of ideas to make any progress on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might look at websockets package... for code ideas, ory just simply use it as it already works. Alternatively, https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server has a simple implementation.

Comment: Using an existing library was my initial plan but `micropython` is so stripped down that I thought me writing a simple server from `socket` would have been easier than trying to fight with all the unsupported extra modules that third-party library brings with them.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but the above github suggestion does it with just standard python libraries you're already using (hashlib, socket, base64, etc.) + socketserver which requires threading.

Comment: So the above approach works - it's just that I'm a massive idiot. There's a bug in my code on `map(lambda x: x.strip().lower(), header)` which was essentially changing the key by converting into lower case for `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header and obviously it was failing. Just wish there was better error so that I didn't have to spend an entire day or two of troubleshooting all the other possibilities besides a bug in my code. I'll post the final working version soon. Thanks for atleast engaging with to be my rubber-duck so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned this in the comment section - there was a bug in my code. Mainly `map(lambda x: x.strip().lower(), header)` which was converting `Sec-WebSocket-Key` value to lowercase causing the key to be invalid. Here's the working code that actually responds with `OK` status now.

```py
import socket
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1

WS_MAGIC_STRING = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
PORT = 8082


def response_key(key):
    GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
    sha1_hash = sha1(key.encode() + GUID.encode())
    response_key = b64encode(sha1_hash.digest()).strip()
    return response_key.decode()


def handshake(key):
    response = (
        "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
        f"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {response_key(key)}\r\n\r\n"
    )
    return response


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(("localhost", PORT))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        request = conn.recv(1024).strip().decode()
        data = request.split("\r\n")
        headers = {}
        for h in data:
            header = h.split(": ")
            if len(header) > 1:
                key, value = map(lambda x: x.strip(), header)
                headers[key.lower()] = value

        if (headers.get("connection") == "Upgrade") and (
            headers.get("upgrade") == "websocket"
        ):
            handshake_response = handshake(
                headers["sec-websocket-key"],
            )
            conn.sendall(handshake_response.encode())
```